# Unable to access 80 port from outside

Tags: networking, server, iptables, amazon-ec2

I am running ubuntu 14.04 with nodejs on Amazon EC2 micro instance.
I enabled both ports in EC2 config:

[image]

I have both apps running on both 80 and 3000 ports:

[image]

Port 3000 is available from outside but port 80 is not whatever I tried:

[image]

Please help me understand what blocks the port.

Comment: I think you should check your security group settings and also nginx config.

Comment: @M.Dm. all security group settings are "Inbound Rules" which I showed you and nginx config should not be the issue as I tried apache and it didn't work as well

Comment: can you attach the output of `sudo netstat -tnlp`?

Comment: @M.Dm. http://prntscr.com/hmztrt

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images?

Comment: Are you sure local `iptables` settings allow inbound traffic? `sudo iptables -L INPUT -n` -> list rules for **INPUT** chain in numeric format.

Comment: check for output here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3gziz4za4ylnnt0/output.txt?dl=0

Comment: @M.Dm. I am not able to ping the server as well

Comment: Try to run `telnet internal_ip 80` (not localhost) inside your EC2 instance (in your case it should be `telnet 172.31.28.195 80`. If there is an error that **telnet** is not found install it `sudo apt-get install telnet`). Also, take a look at web server logs. Usually at `/var/log/nginx/nginx_error.log`

Comment: @M.Dm. it is successful:                                                          
 bitnami@ip-172-31-28-195:~$ telnet 172.31.28.195 80
Trying 172.31.28.195...
Connected to 172.31.28.195.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: I think the best option would be to contact Amazon tech support.